# What can be said about the limit of a converging infinite polynomial?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Suppose we have the following polynomial of infinite order:

$f(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$

Also suppose that $f(x)$ converges to some limit $f^*$ as $x\nearrow\infty$, i.e.

$f(x)\to f^*$ as $x\nearrow\infty$. Where $f^*\in\mathbf{R}$ is some finite real number.

My question is: What can be said about this limit and in particular is it true that the limit can be written in terms of the coefficients $a_n$?. Is it perhaps true that

$f^*=c_0a_0 +c_1a_1 +...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_na_n$

where the $c_n$'s are simply real numbers?. Hence that the value to which the polynomial converges is affine in the coefficients of the original polynomial. I am sitting with a problem for which this seems to be true but am looking for any help or any reference to further dig in to the matter. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I think posting the original problem is a better idea. The formulation of this one is not ideal. For example, the function $f(x)=e^{-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}x^{2n}$ satisfies the assumptions of your problem. We have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. But there are all sorts of relations of the coefficients of the series that equal the limit. Even more, regardless of the example. If there is at least one $a_{i_0}\neq0$ there is always a combination $c_i=0$ for $i\neq i_0$ and $c_{i_0}=f^*/a_{i_0}$ that gives you the limit.

Comment: Hi Benji - Thank you for your response. Okay let me clarify: Consider a function $f(x)$ with expansion $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ Assume $f(x)$ converges to $f^*$ as x tends to infinity. I am interested in $f^*=f^*(a_1,a_2,...)$ - the limit of $f(x)$ as a function of the coefficients in the expansion of $f(x)$. What does this limit look like as function of the $a_n$'s? Is it true that the limit $f^*$ is affine in the coefficients $a_n$. Hope this helps clarifying.

Comment: It seems that the question is about to characterize a linear space of all power series $f(x)$ which converges to the zero as $x\nearrow\infty$. So it seems to be a question from theory of analytic functions of *real* variable.